# Javascript function with arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

Hi just a little javascript question

i need a function like this:

```
        <script>
        function autoSubmit_(){
        var formObject = document.forms['pool_nargument_here'];
        formObject.submit();}
        </script>
```

and i dont really understand how to write it
i just need a js function when called like that:

`autosubmit(42)` gives `var formObject = document.forms['pool_n42'];`

many thx

Comment: You need to learn the basics of computer programming. Function arguments are basic to almost every programming language, and they're pretty much the same in all of them.

Comment: I program in C / Php but I dont know js, I will learn it soon.

Comment: Function arguments in JS are similar to C and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
function autoSubmit_(n){
var formObject = document.forms['pool_n' + n];
formObject.submit();}
</script>
```

You should read up a bit on how parameters and arguments work. Basically, the thing you pass as an argument (as `47` in: `autoSubmit_(47)`) will be put into the corresponding parameter (`n`). The expression `'pool_n' + n` contains a string with the n-value appended to it.

Comment: thx to all, I'll try this! as usual I don't think the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arguments:

```
var formObject = document.forms['pool_'+arguments[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
   <script>
   function autoSubmit (id){
   var formObject = document.forms['pool_n'+id];
   formObject.submit();}
   </script>
```